# Rollback to Stock ROM without having backup of it

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms

i have XOLO Q1000 device which is rooted. I installed custom ROM of cyanogenmod on my device currently , i don't have previous backup of the stock ROM (jelly bean 4.2.1). Now i want the stock rom for my device from where i get that back

Answer (score 0):

In this page you can find the stock rom as well as other tools for IMEIs, drivers and other ROM updates for your phone, the procedure for installing the original firmware should be the same as installing the cyanogenmod, so wipe all and then install

http://www.xolo.in/software-update

Comment: My device is not showing in that list.I have Lava Xolo Q1000